# How to get and store the values of a specific row in a table via JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I store in an array of arrays in JavaScript / jQuery the values of each selected row of the table.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/e8rps0k5/3/)

The event to listen to would be (I think) when the 'Show selected' button is clicked.

For example in JS we would have an array like this:

```
result = []
result[0] = row1
result[0][1] = Gene value for row1 (Gene1)
result[0][2] = Variant value for row1 (Variant1)
result[0][7] = #5 value1 for row1
result[1] = row2
result[1][1] = Gene value for row2 (Gene2)
etc
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this just like so:

```
$("#show-selected").click(function () {
  var results =[];
  $(".variants-table-tbody tr").each(function (index,item) {
      if($(item).find('[name="select-item"]').prop("checked")){
        results.push([
            [$(item).find("td").eq(1).text()],
            [$(item).find("td").eq(2).text()],
            [$(item).find("td").eq(3).text()],
        ]);
      }
  });
  console.log(results);
});
```

this would create the data on checked rows in the format you described.
see https://jsfiddle.net/y4deut3s/

Answer (score 0):

With something like this:

```
$("#show-selected").click(function () {
        var tr = $("tr");
        var array1 = [];
        tr.each(function(index1, trCurrent) {
            var array2 = [];
            var trChildrens = $(trCurrent).children();
            if(($(trChildrens[0]).children()[0]).checked){
                trChildrens.each(function(index2, trChildrensCurrent) {
                    var innerHtml = $(trChildrensCurrent).html();
                    array2.push(innerHtml);
                });
                array1.push(array2);
            }
        });
        console.log(array1);
    });
```

TEST:

[image]